# multi-line text for brace decoration in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, braces, decorations

I'm trying to make a time-line with events by means of tikZ.
Everything is going fine, I found (here) some nice examples and explanations but...
I do a brace decoration for my time-line which has long "caption". What I'm trying is to make this caption multi-line, but it's not working. 
For example, in the text for node I can put `\\` inside the text and it makes the text two line.
But this way is totally useless in text for the brace decoration.
the minimum example is like next

``` \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,titlepage]{report}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{snakes, positioning, decorations.pathreplacing, calc}  
\tikzset{  
    date labels/.style = {  
        % Font  
        font = \sffamily,  
        % Anchor  
        anchor = north,  
        %Angle  
        %rotate = 45  
    }    
}    
\tikzset{   
    event/.style = {    
        %Shape  
        rectangle,  
        % Size  
        rounded corners = 2mm,  
        % Border  
        thick,  
        draw = #1!50,  
        %Filling  
        fill = #1!20,  
        % Font  
        align = center,    
        font = \sffamily\scriptsize,
    }   
}   
\tikzset{  
    side labels/.style = {  
        %Shape  
        rectangle,  
        % Size  
        minimum size = 6mm,  
        rounded corners = 2mm,  
        % Border  
        very thick,  
        draw = black!50,  
        %Filling  
        top color = white,  
        bottom color = black!20,  
        % Font  
        font = \sffamily,  
        % Anchor  
        anchor = east,  
    }  
}  
\begin{document}        
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width = 1pt]  
        \node [side labels] at (-1, 0) {Customer A};  
        \draw[fill = black!100] {[snake] (0, 0)circle[radius=2pt] -- (2, 0)circle[radius=2pt]} -- (7, 0)circle[radius=2pt] -- (9, 0)circle[radius=2pt];  
        \draw (0, -0.05) node [date labels] {1} -- (0, 0.05) node (paid_date) {};  
        \draw (2, -0.05) node [date labels] {30} -- (2, 0.05) node (paid_back_date) {};  
        \draw (7, -0.05) node [date labels] {280} -- (7, 0.05) node (next_paid_date) {};  
        \draw (9, -0.05) node [date labels] {365} -- (9, 0.05) node (stop_date) {};
        \begin{scope}[on grid]
            \node (utility_first) [event = gray] at (-1, 1.25) {$1^{st}$ loan\\utilization};  
            \draw [gray!50] (utility_first) -- (paid_date);  
            \node (start_monitoring) [event = gray] at (1, 1.25) {start\\monitoring};  
            \draw [gray!50] (start_monitoring) -- (paid_date);  
            \node (paid_back) [event = gray] at (2.75, 1.25) {$1^{st}$ loan\\paid back};  
            \draw [gray!50] (paid_back) -- (paid_back_date);  
            \node (utility_second) [event = gray] at (7, 1.25) {$2^{nd}$ loan\\utilization};  
            \draw [gray!50] (utility_second) -- (next_paid_date);  
            \node (stop_monitoring) [event = gray] at (9, 1.25) {stop\\monitoring};  
            \draw [gray!50] (stop_monitoring) -- (stop_date);  
        \end{scope}  
        \draw [decorate, decoration = {brace, amplitude = 10pt, mirror}, xshift = 0pt, yshift = -42pt]  
        ($(paid_back_date.south) + (0, -0.5)$) -- ($(stop_date.south) + (0, -0.5)$) node [black, midway, xshift = 0cm, yshift = -0.6cm] {\scriptsize ``real'' $2^{nd}$ loan utilization period under monitoring = $335$ days};  
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document} ```

what I want is to have the caption for the brace displayed in two lines instead of 1.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities: You can either specify a `text width=<length>` for the node, which will automatically break the text if it exceeds the `<length>`, or you can supply an `align=<alignment option>` and manually break your text using `\\`.

So, either

```
node [align=center,midway,anchor=north,yshift=-1.5ex,font=\scriptsize] { ``real'' $2^{nd}$ loan utilization period\\under monitoring = $335$ days};
```

or

```
node [align=center,text width=5cm,midway,anchor=north,yshift=-1.5ex,font=\scriptsize] {``real'' $2^{nd}$ loan utilization period under monitoring = $335$ days};
```

will yield

[image]